# PySCF calcuation of 'one-index' electrostatic (Hartree) potential

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, python, pyscf

I'm trying to calculate the electrostatic (Hartree) potential corresponding to a single (auxiliary) GTO:

$$v_i({\bf r_1}) = \int d{\bf r}_2~ \frac{\phi_i ({\bf r}_2)}{r_{12}}$$

[Please note that $\phi_i$ is **not** squared].

I have been using the 'fake_mol' delta function trick to calculate the Hartree potential over two GTOs:

$$v_{ij}({\bf r_1})= \int d{\bf r}_2 \frac{\phi_i({\bf r}_2) \phi_j({\bf r}_2)}{r_{12}}$$

by using this code:

```
from pyscf import gto, scf, dft, lib, ao2mo
from pyscf import df, lib
import numpy as np
mol = gto.M(atom = 'Ne 0.00 0.000 0.00')
mol.basis = 'def2tzvp'
mol.cart = True
mol.build()
mf = dft.RKS(mol).density_fit()
mf.run()
Amol = df.addons.make_auxmol(mol, 'def2tzvpjkfit')


coords = mf.grids.coords #coordinates on a grid
fakemol = gto.fakemol_for_charges(coords);
v_ij = df.incore.aux_e2(Amol, fakemol);
```

`v_ij[i, j, p]` represents:

$$v_{ij}(r_1) = \int d{\bf r}_2 \frac{\phi_i({\bf r}_2) \phi_j({\bf r}_2)}{r_{12}}$$

at `r_1 = coords[p]` and thus is of shape `(naux, naux, len(coords))`.

However, I would like to calculate

$$v_i ({\bf r_1} )= \int d{\bf r}_2 \frac{\phi_i({\bf r}_2)}{r_{12}}$$

at `r_1 = coords[p]`. Since $\phi_i$ is **not** squared, this object is not just `v_ij[i, i, p]`
Any ideas on how can I achieve this with PySCF?

Comment: Just write $e^{\alpha r^2} = e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}r^2}e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}r^2}$ and you can easily turn the second form into the first.

Comment: You can turn two-index integrals into one-index integrals with a dummy $s$ function with exponent $0.0$.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?  Were the comments by Ian and Susi helpful?